# Delete more than 20 tickets in vtiger CRM

Tags: vtiger

Is there any possibility to delete bulk tickets (around 1000) in VTIGER CRM, either from application or from source code.

Comment: More specific to Results, if you wants to delete specific leads then create a filter in Ticket modules and then delete those records as mentioned by Lajeesh.

Answer (score 1):

[image: tickets screenshot]

Please check the attached screenshot. I have marked the steps for bulk delete from application.

step 1 : from list view select the checkbox under delete button. which will select all the 20 records in list and at the same time a new link will appear says "select all 1000 records in trouble tickets. click on that " 
step 2 : click delete button

if you want to delete records with specific criteria. for eg: delete closed tickets. then first create a filter for that and then do the steps for delete.

**Delete from database**

run this query

update vtiger_crmentity set deleted=1 where settype='HelpDesk'

Comment: More specific to Results, if you wants to delete specific leads then create a filter in Ticket modules and then delete those records as mentioned by Lajeesh.

Answer (score 1):

its easy go to config_inc.php and put in $list_max_entries_per_page=1000 and go in vtiger crm list view you see 1000 records you can select 1000 and delete them go again to config_inc.php and restore $list_max_entries_per_page=20

see it in github

https://github.com/gothblade/vtiger/blob/master/config.inc.php